# Can I ask about entry-level questions (understanding and definitions) of research-level topics?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

I am currently doing a reading on Teichmuller space and I am having trouble understanding some basic definitions. So I asked these two questions on MSE first:

[Understanding Teichmuller equivalence of marked compact Riemann surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341079/understanding-teichmuller-equivalence-of-marked-compact-riemann-surfaces)

[What is the Sobolev space of maps between surfaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340739/what-is-the-sobolev-space-of-maps-between-surfaces)

They have received some upvotes so they are at least not bad questions. The fact that it hasn't been a day since I posted them might make me seem a little too thirsty for answers, but the thing is, while I was reading Riemann surfaces as a preparation for Teichmuller spaces (like a month ago), I have asked even simpler questions, yet those questions have not received a single answer. Judging from the views they've received, I think I have a pretty good reason to believe my new questions are going to end up just like the old ones. And I don't want to waste any more time waiting for nothing.

Based on that, I would like to know whether it is appropriate to ask these questions (more generally speaking, questions that are not of the form of research questions, but belong to a research-level topic) on this site. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If phrased the right way (so that there is a specific and direct question that will shine light for you), then such questions should be received well on MathOverflow.

Rather than point out possible flaws to a linked version of your question in an (to me) unfamiliar technical area, I encourage you to make a new post to meta, of the following form:

I want to ask this question on MathOverflow.  How can I improve it so that I get a satisfactory answer?

---

### [[Body of question here]]

We can then analyze the wording and point out areas of improvement. Such an example may become useful for future readers.  I also invite you to scour meta for similar examples.

Gerhard "Meta Could Use Some Scouring" Paseman, 2019.09.02.